# Sidebar with letters

Tags: mobile-web, web

I saw this today on Dribbble.

[image: dribbble shot]

I would like to know what the technical name is for that sidebar with letters? If one was searching Google for that, what would one type?

Also, can this be implemented with HTML/CSS/JS?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is commonly called "[alphabetical section index](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=imgo%3A1&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=alphabetical+section+index)".

In terms of affordances, the concept is akin to the cardboard [tabbed index dividers](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=tabbed%20index%20dividers&tbs=imgo:1) featured on paper indexes and directories.

This usability component has also been discussed in this community under the description "small alphabetical index" [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/83857/116190).

A quick search results in several implementations: [1](http://www.matthiassommer.it/programming/web/javascript/alphabetical-list-navigation-with-javascript-html-and-css/), [2](https://spyrestudios.com/how-to-build-alphabetical-index-using-jquery/), [3](https://github.com/i6mi6/react-native-alphabetlistview), [4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@unpourtous/react-native-search-list), [5](https://github.com/rgovindji/react-native-atoz-list).